# as3 - Adding one month

Tags: actionscript-3, date, calendar, monthcalendar

I'm working currently with actionscript 3 and found out, that it always displays one month less than it actually is (currently it displays "21.11.2015", but should display "21.12.2015"). That's why I wanted to know the command for adding "1" to my "my_date.month". I didnt post the code with date and year, just with the month. Thanks in advance.

```
function onTimer(e:TimerEvent):void {
my_date = new Date();
tag.text = "" +my_date.month);  
}
```

Comment: This is the correct value. The Date class is supposed to be used in all languages so that's why some properties are zero based and some are not. The date property is not zero based because it gives a correct result in all languages but the month and day property must eventually be matched with a month and day name in any language and that's why they are zero based (to match a zero based array of month names or day names).

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33087334/why-is-date-dateutcs-first-index-1-and-date-monthutcs-first-index-0/33088109#33088109

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for answering and help. I could make it by forcing an array from 01 till 12. -> Displaying this array solved my question :)

Answer (score -2):

The `month` property of the Date class returns 0 to 11. This aligns with arrays being zero-based, meaning that the **first** element in the array has an index of zero (0).

[Date Class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html):

> month : Number
>   The month (0 for January, 1 for February, and so on) portion of a Date object according to local time.

Comment: Good try but that's not the reason why month start at 0. If it was there would be no reason for date property to start at 0 as well. There's a specific reason why month and day are zero based and date is not.

Comment: @BotMaster I guess you do not understand how Dates are created, take a look at the constructor, i.e. (1999, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0) ... and do the math...

Comment: Nothing to do with math sorry. Just to be clear a Date instance has a date property that gives the day of the month and is not zero based.